# Azure slots :Can i swap only app settings/connection strings?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way we can swap only **app settings**/**connectionstrings** but not code from `Azure App Service slot` using `azure DevOps pipeline` or `Azure CLI`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We are trying to get connectionstring directly from the slot and swap it to prod but not code.

As far as I know, you can use Azure CLI to achieve it.

Appsettings: [az webapp config appsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_appsettings_set)

ConnectString: [az webapp config connection-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/connection-string?view=azure-cli-latest#code-try-5)

You could use Azure CLI to list appsettings/connectionstring. Then you could use the set command to pass the values to the slot.

Here is my sample(In Azure Devops **Azure CLI Task**):

```
$appsettings=az webapp config appsettings list --name webappname -g  ResourcesGroupName   --slot  slotname

$appsettings| Out-File "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\appsettings.json" 

az webapp config appsettings set -g ResourcesGroupName   -n webappname  --settings -slot slotname "@$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\appsettings.json"

$connectstring=az webapp config connection-string list --name webappname -g  ResourcesGroupName   --slot  slotname

$test = $connectstring | ConvertFrom-Json


$test | Select-Object -Property Name,slotSetting ,type,Value | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Name $_.Value 
    $msg =   $_.Name , $_.Value   -join '='
    echo    $msg 

    az webapp config connection-string set --name webappname -g  ResourcesGroupName   -slot slotname -t mysql --settings  $msg 

}
```

**Note:** Here is [an known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/15395) about the az webapp config connection-string set.  It couldn't support to set files in settings parameter for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

**Step 1 :** Create two separated environments in a release as per your needs!

**Step 2 :** Create a variable with the same name as your connection string name in your web.config, one scoped for staging environment and the other for production.

**Step 3 :** Add a Deploy Azure App Service task to each environment.

Then you could use the File transformation and substitution options and mark to make the transformation.  Take a look at [XML Transformation and JSON transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic)

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, Actually, we are trying to achieve a unique case where this would not be feasible. We are trying to get connectionstring directly from the slot and swap it to prod but not code.